# shortest path in maze with possibility to jump

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, maze

I have a maze in which you can jump:

0-field
1-wall
S-start
E-end

A, B, C - possibility to jump. When you enter field with one of this letter you jump to other field with the same letter (in maze there are only two such fields with one letter (two As, two Bs, two Cs).

When you jump from A to second A - you must always go one step further (you cant go back to jump field without moving to at least one another field).

Example maze:

```
1 1 E
A 1 0
S 1 A
```

The path from start S to end E would be (kartezian): (0,0)(0,1)(2,0)(2,1)(2,2)

Another example:

```
A 0 B S
0 1 0 1
0 B 0 1
0 0 A E
```

The output should be (3,3)(2,3)(1,1)(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(2,0)(3,0)

Im using BFS algorhitm it works perfect for normal maze. But cant come up with how to add jump possibility correctly. My current pseudo -code (it works perfect for first example but fails on second):

```
parents[points]; //array of parents
visited[points];    //array describing whether node was already visited

Que q;
q.put(startPoint);
while(!q.isEmpty)
{
     point = q.pop();
     if(CanJumpFromThisField(point))
     {
         jump = getJumpCoordinates(point);
         if(parents[point] != jump)
        continue;
     }
    for(allNeighbours(point)) //neighbour is field from left, righ, top, bottom 
    {
        if(neighbour.val != 1)
        {
        if(!CanJumpFromThisField(neighbour))
        {
            if(!visited(neighbour))
            {
                visited(neighbour) = true;
                parents(neighbour) = point;
                q.put(neighbour);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            jump = getJumpCoordinates(neighbour);
            if(!visited(jump))
            {
                parents(neighbour) = point;
                visited(neighbour)=true;
                parents(jump)=neighbour;
                visited(jump)=neighbour;
                q.put(jump);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it would be worth checking `maximum flow` applied to a `maze` problem

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of doing a BFS from startPoint S to EndPoint E, do a BFS from E till you visit all points.

2) Store the shortest path's length from every point to E

3) To find the path, traverse from S, and choose the neighbour with smallest path length and keep traversing till you reach E.

Note: Jumping points should also be considered as neighbours

Complexity: O(sizeof(Grid))

Answer (score 0):

Just treat boths neighbors and neighbors as 'destinations'. Introduce a new method which enumerates all possible destinations (i.e. neighbors and jump destinations) from a given point.

A valid neighbor is a neighbor which is not a wall (i.e. `!= 1`). This will greatly simplify your loop.

```
while(!q.isEmpty)
{
   point = q.pop();
   for(allDestinations(point)) //neighbours and jump destinations
   {
      if(!visited(neighbour))
      {
        visited(neighbour) = true;
        parents(neighbour) = point;
        q.put(neighbour);
      }
   }
}
allDestinations(point) returns list of points
{
  result = allDestinations(point).where (p=>p.Value != 1);
  if(CanJumpFromThisField(point))
  {
     jump = getJumpCoordinates(point);
     if (jump != point) 
       result.add(jump);
  }
}
```

Again, this is some funny pseudocode, but I think you get the point. Don't put too much logic into one method or loop. It makes things hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The BFS assumes that reaching a specific node is the same 'success' despite the path leading to the node - and that is untrue in your problem. Consider your 4x4 maze

```
 A 0 B S
 0 1 0 1
 0 B 0 1
 0 0 A E
```

When the analysis makes B-B jump it flows from cell (1,1) in all directions. It soon finds (2,0) and makes A-A jump. However then the path from A(0,3) going south meets the path from B(1,1) going west-north and they cancel each other.

The problem is in using the geometric 'adjacent cell' relation of your maze as a transition relation in the BFS's graph. In the maze above cells (2,1) and (1,0) are both adjacent to (2,0), and you *can* make steps (1,0)(2,0) and (2,0)(2,1). However, you *can not* go (1,0)(2,0)(2,1) path, because you are forced to jump once you entered (2,0).

The simple solution is: for every jump `u-v` remove cells `u` and `v` from the maze (make them inaccessible from their adjacent cells) and for each `x` adjacent to `u` and each `y` adjacent to `v` add an `x-y` branch to the graph.

Alas it works only for mazes without adjacent jupms. For example this modification

```
 A 0 B S
 0 1 0 1
 0 1 0 1
 0 B A E
```

makes analysis much more complicated. In this case you would have to use one-way branches, for example allow only `x->u`, `u->y`, `y->v` and `v->x` transitions. Or switch from breadth-first to depth-first search...